# What characters can have their clothing changed?

Tags: sword-art-online-fatal-bullet

Some characters can have their clothing changed. Some of them can only change their clothing if requested by the Customizable Character (eg. Kureha) and other ones only by Kirito (like Asuna and Sinon).

What characters can have their clothing changed?